# laravel 5 collection pull method prints nothing

Tags: php, mysql, laravel-5

my controller method returns this array, I know data is being returned

```
return view('bill')->with('itemarray',Menu::where('itemname','Apple Pie')->get());
```

my view is suppose to act on it like this but the print_r method prints the array but the td of the table has nothing in it and I am not getting an error

```
@if(isset($itemarray))
<table>
<tr>
<td>{{ $itemarray->pull('itemname') }} <!-- this prints nothing --> </td>
<td> {{ $itemarray->pull('itemprice') }} <!-- this prints nothing --> </td> 
</tr>  
</table>
<p>  {{  print_r($itemarray) }} <!-- this prints ok --> </p>
@endif
```

Comment: Do you expect one item of type `Menu` or multiple? Because that's not how `pull` works.

Comment: @lukasgeiter I expect one item, just the name and price from the record.... which method should I use because `{{ $itemarray->itemname }}` give me `undefined property` error

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The underlying problem here is that `get()` *always* returns a **collection**. Even if your query only has one or zero results. It's recommended to use `first()` if you expect only one result:

```
return view('bill')->with('item',Menu::where('itemname','Apple Pie')->first());
```

This means that you will then be dealing with a model in your view, so:

```
@if(isset($item))
<table>
<tr>
<td>{{ $item->itemname }}</td>
<td> {{ $item->itemprice }}</td> 
</tr>  
</table>
@endif
```

---

I also suggest you change `isset()` to `!empty()` as this will also check for `null` (if no records match)

```
@if(!empty($item))
```